# Youtube controls are missing in iPhone X ionic 3 app

Tags: angular, iframe, youtube, ionic2, youtube-iframe-api

I'm trying to embed youtube player in my ionic 3 application. I have used [iFrame player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Retrieving_video_information) to embed youtube player. It is working fine on all the devices except iPhone X, iOS 11.3. In iPhone X controls are missing.

[image: Screenshot reference for the issue].

To create youtube player, I'm using following code:

```
 this.youtubePlayer = new YT.Player(id, {
      videoId: '',
      height:'100%',
      width:'100%',
      playerVars: { playsinline:1, rel:0, showinfo : 0, modestbranding:1 },
      allowsInlineMediaPlayback : true,
      events: {
        'onReady': (event)=>{ 
          console.log("ready");
        },    
      }
    });
```

**Ionic Info**

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.18.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.18.0

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.3
Cordova Platforms  : ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0
```

System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.2
Node       : v8.9.1
npm        : 5.5.1
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.0.1 Build version 9A1004
```

Any ideas ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you Try

```
this.youtubePlayer = new YT.Player(id, {
          videoId: '',
          height:'100%',
          width:'100%',
          controls: 1,    ► HERE IS PARAM
          playerVars: { playsinline:1, rel:0, showinfo : 0, modestbranding:1 },
          allowsInlineMediaPlayback : true,
          events: {
            'onReady': (event)=>{ 
              console.log("ready");
            },    
          }
        });
```

more Supported parameters :

[Click me](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Parameters)